# How to subscribe a Watson IoT Device events using MQTT?

Tags: ibm-watson, paho, watson-iot

I'm creating a MQTT client with Paho and Python to connect with a device in Watson IoT Platform.

I correctly assembled the broker:

```
<org>.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com:1883
```

And the client:

```
d:<org>:<type>:<deviceId>
```

And published values to this topic:

```
iot-2/evt/<eventName>/fmt/json Payload: {"db",56}
```

With the authentication:
username: use-token-auth Password:

And all OK.

But I tried to subscribe the topic iot-2/type//id//evt//fmt/json

And the connection always closes, and the dashboard says:

Closed connection. The topic is not valid: iot-2/type/sound/id/ipt/evt/db/fmt/json The topic does not match an authorized rule

Why this don't work? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot subscribe to an events topic using using a clientID of **"d:::"**. You need to generate an APIKey and use a clinetID of **"a:orgId:appId"** to subscribe to topic **iot-2/type/device_type/id/device_id/evt/event_id/fmt/format_string** (iot-2/type/sound/id/ipt/evt/db/fmt/json)

You can use as reference: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQP8H/iot/platform/applications/mqtt.html