# on_subscribe not working - paho python with IBM iot platform

Tags: python-3.x, ibm-cloud, mqtt, paho

I tried my subscriber which is written using Paho python client with HiveMQ broker and it worked just fine, but it is not working with IBM.

from [Subscribing to application status messages](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQP8H/iot/platform/applications/mqtt.html), and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57119167/how-to-subscribe-a-watson-iot-device-events-using-mqtt), I implemented suscriber client as following (I got the `"a:<ORG-ID>:<App-ID>"` from the apps section of my IBM Watson platform):

```
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("CONNACK received with code %d." % (rc))
    (result, mid) = client.subscribe("iot-2/app/MyAppID/sensordata", 2)
    print("result: ", result, ", mid: ", mid)

    if result == paho.MQTT_ERR_SUCCESS:
        print("success in subscribing.")


def on_subscribe(client, userdata, mid, granted_qos):
    print("Subscribed: "+str(mid)+" "+str(granted_qos))


client = paho.Client("a:<ORG-ID>:<App-ID>")

# adding callbacks to client
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_subscribe = on_subscribe
client.on_message = on_message
client.username_pw_set("a-<ORG-ID>-<App-ID>","my authentication token")

client.tls_set( ca_certs=None, certfile=None, keyfile=None, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
           tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS, ciphers=None)


client.connect("<ORG-ID>.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com", 8883, 60)
client.loop_start()
```

When I run the project, I get rc with value of `0` which means `successful connection`.

and this is the `on_connect()` callback prints:

> CONNACK received with code 0.
> result:  0 , mid:  2
> success in subscribing.

And the `on_subscribe()` callback is not being called. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to **Subscribe to application status messages** then

An application can subscribe to monitor status of one or more applications, for example:

```
Subscribe to topic iot-2/app/appId/mon
```

Note: To subscribe to updates for all applications, use the MQTT "any" wildcard character (+) for the appId comp

Based on above, the line:

```
(result, mid) = client.subscribe("iot-2/app/MyAppID/sensordata", 2)
```

should be

```
(result, mid) = client.subscribe("iot-2/app/MyAppID/mon", 2)
```

or

```
(result, mid) = client.subscribe("iot-2/app/+/mon", 2)
```

If want to receive sensor data, then use the below line:

> Subscribe to topic iot-2/type/device_type/id/device_id/evt/event_id/fmt/format_string

You would need to replace: device_type, device_id, event_id, format_string(could be json, txt)

For every possible event:

```
(result, mid) = client.subscribe("iot-2/type/+/id/+/evt/+/fmt/+",2)
```

Comment: Thank you but what about the publisher's topic. the publisher's topic is not in this format, it is just a word(`sensor`). should I change that topic too?

Comment: The topic format for publishing events using the same clietid (a:org:appif) would be iot-2/type/device_type/id/device_id/evt/event_id/fmt/format_string. But the device_type, device_id needs to be created first in the WIoTP. event_id can be (sensor) if you want to, or what the sensor is actually reading, like temp or color, whatever have you.